# Getting error 404 while logging In to website using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to login In to a website javandi.com with the login url as https://publisher.javandi.com/#/login. I am using google script for this purpose. I don't know whether it is using post or get method to get logged In.

I tried few of the codes from stack-overflow but none of them works. I tried to write my own code with get or post method but still it doesn't work. here is the code which I have tried. (taken from stack-overflow). It should login with code 303, but it gives error code 404 and the response text says "Error, cannot post".
[I  have logged the error code and response text, here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ayBJ.png).

```
function loginToSite(){
  var url = "https://publisher.javandi.com/#/login"; //change this.

  var payload = {
    "username":"muusername", //not real.
    "password":"mypassword" //not real
  };


   var headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Cookie':'...',
  }

  var opt = {
    "payload":payload,
    "headers": headers,
    "method":"post",
    "followRedirects" : false,
     "muteHttpExceptions":true,
    "Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI(url),opt);
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  if ( response.getResponseCode() == 404 ) { //could not log in.
    var result = "Couldn't login. Please make sure your username/password is correct.";
  } 
  else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 303 ) { //login was successful. you might receive 302 response code as well depending upon the site. So try changing it to 302.
     var result = "Logged in successfully";
     var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
     var header = {
       'Cookie':cookie[1] //taking the second cookie because when redirected, a new cookie is set. If the page does not redirect, you might need to use cookie[0] here. Try it out yourself!
     };
  }
//Logger.log(result);
}
```

Comment: The `#/login` in the URL says this is a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). It's unlikely to be accepting any POST requests at that URL. Monitor your browser's _Network_ console while you log in normally to see the requests that are made

Comment: Respected @Phil, I have seen the network console. I can log In by manually entering the credentials. even after logged In and dashboard page is loaded, network console says this.  
**GET https://publisher.javandi.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**